# Android native library Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015

I am developing an library in C++, that support both Windows and Android. I used Visual Studio 2013 with vs-android. I decided to move to Visual 2015, that supports Android native development. If I start new native application project, it's work fine both on emulator and physical device, but I have a problem with my project ported from VS 2013. Windows configs works ok, but I don't have option to add Android target in project configurations. Is it possible to add support for Android without creating new solution? I was looking for that on MSDN, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go will be to add an Android project from the Visual C++-> Cross-platform section in the File->New project menu, and share common code between two platform used a shared project component. The 'OpenGLES2' application should provide a good example to follow on how do this.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/61b15204-e6ae-4f9a-a59a-b3d916e1bb3f

Hope this helps.